# Execute a .cql script from neo4j shell

Tags: windows, shell, neo4j, cypher

Using Neo4j Community 2.2.3 on Windows, i open the Neo4j shell by starting Neo4j, selecting Options, selecting Command Prompt and Neo4jShell command.
From there, how is it possible to execute a script containing multiple lines of Cypher?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your cypher commands in `filename.cql`
and write

```
neo4jshell -file filename.cql
```

in the command prompt